# Referring an input dataset in itself - Recursion using POINT option - SAS

Tags: sas

I have the below dataset wherein each employee is tied up to a manager position. 
Now the employee's manager's employee ID needs to be found out using the manager position. 
If in the immediate manager's position none is ACTIVE then we need to find the manager's manager position and find that any ACTIVE employee is tied to that posotion. This needs to be continued till an ACTIVE manager is found.

```
ID -> Employee ID    
PSTN -> Employee Position code    
MPSTN-> Manager Position code    
STAT -> Employee Status (T - Term A - Active)
```

Input Dataset:

```
data input;  
input id pstn mpstn stat$;  
datalines;  
1 10 30 A  
2 20 30 T  
3 30 40 T  
6 30 40 T  
4 40 50 A  
7 40 50 T
5 50 50 A
;
run;
```

Output Dataset expected:

```
ID MGR_ID
1  4
2  4
3  4
6  4
4  5
7  5
5  5
```

I tried the RECURSIVE nature of the problem with POINT function.

It's working fine except for the recursive part - wherein searching for the next level active manager.

```
data output ;
  set input;
  flag = 1;
  do I = 1 to last while (flag=1);
    set input(rename=(pstn=pstn1 stat=stat1 mpstn=mpstn1 id=id1)) nobs=last 
                                                                  point=I;
    if mpstn = pstn1 and stat1 = 'A' then
     do;
        MGRID = id1;
        I=1;
        flag=0;
     end;
    else flag=1;
  end;
run;
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hash map to loop through the input dataset to look up the values.  Instead of recursively calling the lookup, I suggest putting the lookup into a `do while()` loop.

```
data input;  

input id pstn mpstn stat$;  
format stat $1.;
datalines;  
1 10 30 A  
2 20 30 T  
3 30 40 T  
6 30 40 T  
4 40 50 A  
7 40 50 T
5 50 50 A
;
run;

data out(keep=id mgr_id);
set input;
format pstn1 id1 mpstn1 best.
       stat1 $1.;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash mgr(dataset:"input(rename=(pstn=pstn1 stat=stat1 mpstn=mpstn1 id=MGR_ID))");
    rc = mgr.definekey("pstn1");
    rc = mgr.definedata("MGR_ID");
    rc = mgr.definedata("mpstn1");
    rc = mgr.definedata("stat1");
    rc = mgr.definedone();
end;

found = 0;
do while(^found);
    pstn1 = mpstn;
    rc = mgr.find();
    if stat1 = "A" then do;
        /*MGR Found*/
        found = 1;
    end;
    else if rc then do;
        /*RC^=0 when lookup fails*/
        MGR_ID = .;
        found = 1;
    end;
    else do;
        mpstn = mpstn1;
    end;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Agreed, a hash table is definitely the easiest way to do this in SAS.